# Is there a web.py for python3 yet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py, web-frameworks

when I try to install with pip3:

`$ pip3 install web.py`

I receive an error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-i9tahb62/web.py/
```

I see old support forums stating that the web.py has not yet updated, but it's coming, and their github has a python3 and py3 branch.  Yet, I can't find any documentation on web.py python3 version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `web.py` project is now publishing a pre-release version to PyPI that is Python 3 compatible; install it with:

```
pip install web.py==0.40-dev1
```

as outlined [in their *Getting Started* section](http://webpy.org/). You can also install the latest pre-release with

```
pip install --pre web.py
```

These releases are Python 3 compatible (Python 3.5 and up).

You can also install the current GitHub under-development codebase with:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/webpy/webpy#egg=web.py
```

The project uses Travis for continuous integration [has configured Python 3.5](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/.travis.yml) to run the test suite for each commit, since [June 2016](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/commit/6dc62af5da46d281cda5d301110b1d62e6201350#diff-354f30a63fb0907d4ad57269548329e3); the configuration has since been updated regularly to add new Python 3.x releases.

Comment: Awesome Thanks!  Makes sense, I must have overlooked that documentation!

Comment: checked, yep that command successfully installed `web.py==0.40.dev0`

Comment: Alternatively, `pip install --pre web.py` also works.

Comment: @perimosocordiae: Thanks for the heads-up, I updated my answer. That command installs [pre-releases from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/web.py/#history), that's not quite the same thing as installing from github (but arguably a better idea). Glad to see that the project is at least pushing some pre-releases out!